# Drupal 8 - Mixed Content for SVG icons

Tags: drupal, https, drupal-8

I use Drupal 8.

I try to load SVG icon files in HTTPS but in production, my website load each SVG icon file in HTTP.

Files are in *core/themes/stable/images/core/icons/etc...* as:

http://www.example.com/core/themes/stable/images/core/icons/bebebe/hamburger.svg
http://www.example.com/core/themes/stable/images/core/icons/787878/file.svg

On site-information page (http://www.example.com/admin/config/system/site-information), I have the URL in **HTTP** and not in **HTTPS**.

COuld you help me please, to force HTTPS to load SVG file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe an issue due to a proxy in front of drupal. I faced exactly the same issue as yours and I've configured a reverse proxy in my settings.php file and it was solved.

You could give a try adding those lines to your settings.php :

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Also, there is a thread on drupal.org about the HTTPS issue : https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2842049